# (Java) Why is writing 0x12.2P2 correct but not 0x12.2F?

Tags: java, double, point, literals, floating

I am just beginning to learn java and had a question about literals.

Code:

```
class what_is_px_literals {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    float a = 0x12; //Question Line
    System.out.print("\nThis is the number in:\n\tHexdecimal:\t0x12.2\n\tDecimal:\t"+a+"\n\tWorking of P\t"+0x12.2P2+"\n");
}
}
```

The above code compiles without errors. However rewriting the line as :

```
float a = 0x12.2 //or float a = 0x12.2F or double a = 0x12.2D
```

gives an error.

Why does it give an error when numbers are added after the decimal point?

Why is  this line of code wrong:

```
float a = 0x12.2 //or float a = 0x12.2F or double a = 0x12.2D
```

Comment: Basically, because that's the format of hex floating point literals. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic reason is this notation was added for precise representation not as a convenience. It is expected that the exponent will be given in base 2 as it is in the internal representation of the floating point value.

> Why does it give an error when numbers are added after the decimal point?

It's not used for hexadecimals as these are used for values where such a point alone wouldn't be useful. You have to provide the exponent to use this notation.

e.g. from the source for Double.

```
public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023; // 1.7976931348623157e+308

public static final double MIN_NORMAL = 0x1.0p-1022; // 2.2250738585072014E-308
```

Comment: Then how are floating point numbers to be represented in hexadecimal form?

Comment: @Aswath.S you have to 0x at the start and a Pn at the end. Eg 1 is 0x1p0